# Webscraping using Selenium on Raspberry Pi Zero: Status code was: -4

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, raspberry-pi, webdriver

I am very new to web scraping/coding/raspberry pi. I am trying to web scrape using a headless Raspberry Pi zero. I am working off the example shown below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)  # Update with the actual path


driver.get("https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

I have saved this file as "webscrapingexample.py", moved it onto my Raspberry Pi, where I am running it using $ python webscrapingexample.py. This gives me the following error:

```
 $ python webscrapingexample.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fanoeline/webscrapingexample.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)  # Update with the actual path
  File "/home/fanoeline/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/fanoeline/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/fanoeline/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -4
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? I think the "-4" status code has something to do with the system not being able to open the file?

I have tried installing and re-installing selenium, chromium etc.

Comment: Note that the call that returns the `-4` value is `assert_process_still_running` , which seems like a basic problem. Sorry I only know a tea-spoons worth about python, so don't know where to send you next. Search for `assert_process_still_running`? G Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is how I solved it on my Zero W with a headless config:

1. Flash the SD card with the Buster version of the Pi OS.

[image]

2. Run through the initial setup (you will need to connect keyboard / mouse / monitor) to get it joined to the network, setup user accounts, time zones etc.
3. Run the following command:

   `sudo apt install --reinstall chromium-chromedriver`
4. Run your Python script making sure to use the python3 command, as Buster comes with Python version 2 and 3.

This got it going for me, hopefully it will work for you as well.